# Null input params using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, input, parameters

I have a question about how to receive an input param from my view because it's always NULL.

This is the controller:

```
if session[:usuario_id]                 
  cpusuario = Usuario.new
  cpusuario.user = params[:correo]
  cpusuario.ldap = 1
  cpusuario.activo = 1
  cpusuario.tipo = "Docente"
  cpusuario.save
  redirect_to controller:"secretarias", action: "index"
else
  redirect_to controller:"forminst", action: "index"
end
```

This is the view:

```
<input type="text" name="correo" class="form-control" required>
```

Comment: Can you add the text of the contents of what is actually getting sent over when the form is submitted from the terminal?  Or, does anything show up in the terminal if you add "  puts(params[:correo])  " as the first line of the method ?

Comment: When i print params[:correo] it doesn't show nothing.

Comment: can you paste the form code into your question, that value is not getting sent with the data, and since it is the only params object I am curious about how the form looks.

Comment: Can you also add the form tag and the method your using in it?